# With Secret Santa, is there a word for "the person you drew"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

If John is the secret Santa of Sarah, meaning that John needs to buy a present for Sarah, what is Sarah to John? The only thing I can think of is "the person he drew". What would be a good word or concise description to describe this relation?

Comment: Possibly his 'Secret Santa recipient' as in the person who will recieve his present. I'm pretty sure that Secret Santa hasn't been going long enough for a proper designation to exist.

Comment: Traditionally, Santa delivers presents to all the good boys and girls, so the recipient is a _child_. But  it might sound bizarre for John to say that "...Sarah is my child", and for him to declare that she is his "good girl" is probably worse.

Comment: Sarah is John's secret santa target

Comment: Sarah is John's prey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best word to fit the given scenario would be [*giftee*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/giftee).

*Giftee* means the person on the receiving end of a gift.

This means that Sarah would be John's *giftee* because she will be the one receiving the gift.